# Invalid Config, Exiting abnormally when launching zookeper from Kafka

Tags: apache-zookeeper

while doing setup facing the following issue

```
C:\ProgramData\confluent-6.2.1\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties
[2021-10-12 18:16:00,983] INFO Reading configuration from: zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2021-10-12 18:16:00,985] WARN zookeeper.properties is relative. Prepend .\ to indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2021-10-12 18:16:00,986] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing zookeeper.properties
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:157)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:113)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: zookeeper.properties file is missing
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.doFailForNonExistingPath(VerifyingFileFactory.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.validate(VerifyingFileFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.VerifyingFileFactory.create(VerifyingFileFactory.java:40)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:142)
        ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: 1) You need to show the property file 2) Dont run Kafka from CMD https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not configure the location of the properties file (zookeeper.properties file is missing) in a correct manner. You can fist double check if it exists and then supply the file at launch as in following example from Linux command line (and for a service it will be the same):

**bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon config/zookeeper.properties**

Here the folder is relative to the current one, but an absolute path is safer. Beware that in windows the slashes will be inverted, so in your case, the correct command should be something like:

**C:\ProgramData\confluent-6.2.1\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\ProgramData\confluent-6.2.1\config\zookeeper.properties**